# How do I install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS With RVM and With Passenger for Apache2

Tags: ruby, apache, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble installing Ruby on Rails via [RVM](https://rvm.io) with Passenger for Apache2. I do not know weather I need to install some more dependency's for Rails or what. I have tried for the last month now and can still not figure it out.

I would be very grateful if someone could put down in the suggestions a list of commands I would need to install all of this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For rails, try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade

## Git y Curl
sudo apt-get install -y git curl
sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev

## Javascript Runtime (nodejs)      
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

## FreeTDS
sudo apt-get install -y freetds-dev

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you by chance know how to configure Passenger with Apache2?

Comment: Let me see

Try:

`$ gem install passenger
$ passenger-install-apache2-module`

After, go to /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf and add the virtual host.

Something like that:

`LoadModule passenger_module /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.x/gems/passenger-x/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
 <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerRoot /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.x/gems/passenger-x
    PassengerDefaultRuby /home/username/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.x/ruby
 </IfModule>`